# Application to control phone call volume independently from main volume

Tags: macos, audio, software-recommendation, sound-volume, call

Simply put, if I accept/receive a phone call or FaceTime audio phone call, then I prefer the volume to be louder than what it usually is at.

This does not sound problematic. Why not just adjust the volume before and after, right? The problem is when I am listening to music or watching a video. Then, since I increased the volume for a phone call, the volume of the music or video blares very loudly immediately after ending the phone call.

So, I was wondering if there was an application, service, etc., that would solve this issue.